# Split items in '∑ Values' value label of pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[Pivot table with multiple items in "∑ Values Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mH2C.png)

There are multiple subject marks aggregated as (a)Result (b)Goal and (c)Difference of Result.

These 3 aggregation are put in '∑ Values' values label of pivot.
As shown in image data shows as group-(a) followed by group-(b) followed by group-(c).
I would like to show data as group-(a1)/group-(b1)/group-(c1)/group-(a2)/group-(b2)/group-(c2)
 i.e. All one subject, [say English] (a)Result (b)Goal and (c)Difference together followed by next subject [say Maths].
 My desired result is marked as Yellow in the image.
Your Help! will help me. Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: In the "Columns" box, drag "SubjectName" to be above "Sum Values".

Comment: Question is I have two summations i.e. (a)total marks (b)percentage marks. By default excel shows all subjects total marks and then all subject percentage marks[total:eng, maths and percentage:eng,maths]. I would like to show total marks of english followed by percentage marks of english and that way other subjects.[total:eng,percentage:eng,total:maths,percentage:maths..]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go to Pivot tabel options-->Display-->[select] Classic PivotTable layout(enables dragging of fields in the grid)**

 This option allows custom field layout