# What are these signs that show up in my Pivot Tables?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am building a lot of Pivot Tables using PowerPivot and I saw there are some pivot tables that have Sigma signs in the Pivot Fields like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTd4A.jpg):

[image: screenshot example]

These signs seem to appear only on some Pivot Tables, so anybody can tell me what's up with the signs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## ∑

...is the ***summation*** symbol.

> In mathematics, summation (capital Greek sigma symbol: ∑; <sub>Unicode:</sub> `U+2211`<sub>; HTML:</sub> `&#8721;`) is the addition of a sequence of numbers; the result is their sum or total. If numbers are added sequentially from left to right, any intermediate result is a partial sum, prefix sum, or running total of the summation. <sub>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation))</sub>

For the summation of the sequence of consecutive integers from 1 to 100, one could use an addition expression involving an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) (`…`) to indicate the missing terms: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + … + 99 + 100`. In this case, the reader can easily guess the pattern. However, for more complicated patterns, one needs to be precise about the rule used to find successive terms, which can be achieved by using the summation operator "Σ". Using this sigma notation the above summation is written as:

[image: ∑ i = ⁡ 1 100 i . {\displaystyle \sum _{i\mathop {=} 1}^{100}i.} \sum _{i{\mathop {=}}1}^{100}i.]

The value of this summation is 5050. It can be found without performing 99 additions, since it can be shown (for instance by mathematical induction) that:

[image: ∑ i = ⁡ 1 n i = n ( n + 1 ) 2 {\displaystyle \sum _{i\mathop {=} 1}^{n}i={\frac {n(n+1)}{2}}} \sum _{i{\mathop {=}}1}^{n}i={\frac {n(n+1)}{2}}]

...for all natural numbers n.[5](http://graphemica.com/%E2%88%91) More generally, formulae exist for many summations of terms following a regular pattern.

---

Or, to *summ*arize the definition:

> **sum·ma·tion**    səˈmāSH(ə)n/    *Noun*
>
> 1. The process of adding things together.
>
>    - <sub>*‘the summation of numbers of small pieces of evidence’*</sub>
> 2. A summary.
>
>    - <sub>*‘two summations of his work were published’*</sub>

---

## *Short Answer*:

### **[Replace the `∑` symbol with *`Sum:`* where it appears in Pivot Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**.

---

### More information:

- Stack Overflow: [Split items in '∑ Values' value label of Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38260463/8112776)
- Book Preview: [Power Excel 2016 with Mr. Excel: Master Pivot Tables, Subtotals, Charts](http://hhttps//books.google.ca/books?id=G_sUDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA653&dq=%E2%88%91%20excel%20pivot%20table&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgwtOYs4nZAhVJxWMKHdryDjgQuwUIODAC#v=onepage&q=%E2%88%91%20excel%20pivot%20table&f=falsettp://)
- [More about the symbol](http://graphemica.com/%E2%88%91)
- Wikipedia: [Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)
- [Use a Pivot Table to Summarize Detailed Data](http://www.excelarticles.com/LE10ePub-316.html)
- ubc.ca `.pdf`: [The Summation Operator](http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/dwhistler/students/sumrule.pdf)

Comment: Good explanatory answer as usual. I will +1 before I VTC OP's answer off-topic as this has nothing to do with programming :(. But nevertheless, I always appreciate the detailed explanations you provide.